# collocation: perform / expand its purchase of

Tags: collocations

Can the verbs "expand" and "perform" be used in the following?

> The company decided to **perform** / **expand** its purchase of real estate in Japan.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**perform** would be awkward and unusual.  We *make* a purchase or *complete* a purchase or *go forward with* a purchase.

If we are working with some computer software, one of whose features is the ability to buy and sell stocks, bonds, and other investments, then we might "perform a purchase" but the reference there is not to the purchase directly but to the function of the application. It would be similar to

> I wanted to **do a "save"** and the app froze up.

**expand its purchase of**  might be used, but it is in a rather formal register. It might be clearer and less stuffy with **purchasing**.

> The company decided to expand its purchasing of real estate in Japan.